# Can you generate new asm files based on old ones? And if so what is the most efficent way?

Tags: python, assembly, code-generation

Let's say I have a lot of .asm files on a python program (It can also be binary strings, hex strings or whatever you would like). How can I use those files to generate new files that function roughly the same (It's for an assembly game).

The thing is I have a lot of assembly players that were really good at the game and I wondered if I can somehow use natural selection to breed better assembly bots.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like superoptimization ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superoptimization)).

e.g. [STOKE](https://github.com/StanfordPL/stoke) starts with a sequence of asm instructions and stochastically modifies it looking for shorter / faster sequences that do the same thing.

(Or STOKE can start from scratch looking for an asm sequence that gives the desired result for a set of test-cases.)

It's open source, so have a look at the algorithms they use to modify asm and test-run the code.  Of course it's possible if you have data structures that represent operands and opcodes.

---

See also [Applying Genetic Programming to Bytecode and
Assembly](https://digitalcommons.morris.umn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1013&context=horizons), an academic paper from 2014.

I haven't read it, but hopefully it addresses ways to recombine code from different mutations and maybe get something useful more often than you get garbage that steps on the registers from the other code.  (That's the major trick with random changes to code, especially in assembly where there are *lots* of non-useful instruction sequences.)

Comment: It sounds more like the original poster wants to generate programs for a game like Core War.

Comment: @RossRidge: I agree, and that's what I was thinking when I wrote the answer.  Superoptimization techniques probably work for evolving a program into  a new one, given the right test-cases to evaluate its fitness.  IDK about combining parts of *two* sources, though, like a real genetic algo.  Producing working asm out of that sounds harder.

Comment: This really looks like what I'm looking for! I'll try it now!

Comment: Do you have any alternatives?

Comment: @Hexer: The wikipedia article lists several superoptimizers besides STOKE.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah but the game has very specific requirements. The game's instructions and opcodes have to be supported by an 8086 processor and you can only use 16-bit instructions.

Comment: @Hexer: Oh, so it's already x86.  You might be able to adapt one of the existing open-source superoptimizers more easily than writing your own from scratch.  I wasn't suggesting you could just *use* an existing program unmodified, although it's closer than I was imagining. You might also want to look at [Applying Genetic Programming to Bytecode and
Assembly](https://digitalcommons.morris.umn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1013&context=horizons), an academic paper from 2014.